# Extract the first occurency of text between 2 patterns

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, ash

I have a text file like this

```
----PAT1----
textaa1
textbb1
textcc1
.......
----PAT2----
----PAT1----
textaa2
textbb2
textcc2
.......
----PAT2----
```

I want to extract the first text between `"----PAT1----"` and `"----PAT2----"` icluding both patterns

So the output will be:

```
----PAT1----
textaa1
textbb1
textcc1
.......
----PAT2----
```

How to do that with `sed` or `awk` ?

I tried the following but it does not work

```
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/p' file
```

Other questions are showing how to extract all patterns, but they are not indicating how to extract only the first one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Comment: @Inian Other questions are showing how to extract all patterns (And I know that), but they are not indicating how to extract only the first one

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180663/how-to-select-first-occurrence-between-two-patterns-including-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `awk` possibility would be something like

```
awk '/PAT1/ {f=1} /PAT2/ {print; exit} f' file
```

It would be more complicated to exclude that match, but we could do a similar approach, where we use a flag to decide whether or not to print the line and use the patterns to toggle that flag:

```
awk 'BEGIN {f=1} /PAT1/ {if(first == 0) {f=0}; first=1} /PAT2/ {if(f == 0) {f=1; next}}' f' file
```

That would print every line except the first block of lines between the patterns, including the pattern lines themselves.

Comment: what if I want to remove  it from the file and not extract it ? What I have to do ?

Comment: @MOHAMED I've updated to include removing those lines

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: golfed... `awk '/PAT1/{f=1} f; /PAT2/{f=0; exit}'` and `awk '/PAT1/ && !d{f=1} !f; /PAT2/{f=0; d=1}'` and there is an extra `'` in second solution... should be `{f=1; next}} f'`

Answer (score 4):

Use `q` to quit on matching `PAT2`

```
$ sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{p;/PAT2/q}' ip.txt 
----PAT1----
textaa1
textbb1
textcc1
.......
----PAT2----
```

See also [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)